# MAC Intellij Idea can not run Web Project On port 80

Tags: macos, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have a Web application project with J2EE , and I want to run my web application on port 80 with apache tomcat, i give this error :

> 4:31:34 PM Error running Test: Address localhost:80 is already in use
>   4:31:37 PM Error running Test: Unable to open debugger port : java.net.SocketException "Socket closed"

i use this command to show all process

```
Meysams-MacBook-Pro:~ meysamfatheepanah$ lsof -Pn -i4
COMMAND    PID              USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
UserEvent  309 meysamfatheepanah    4u  IPv4 0x680181e2905eeb01      0t0  UDP *:*
SystemUIS  341 meysamfatheepanah    9u  IPv4 0x680181e2905ed559      0t0  UDP *:*
SystemUIS  341 meysamfatheepanah   10u  IPv4 0x680181e2905f00a9      0t0  UDP *:*
SystemUIS  341 meysamfatheepanah   13u  IPv4 0x680181e2905ed2f1      0t0  UDP *:57792
SystemUIS  341 meysamfatheepanah   15u  IPv4 0x680181e2905ed089      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd   366 meysamfatheepanah   24u  IPv4 0x680181e2905edc91      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd   366 meysamfatheepanah   28u  IPv4 0x680181e28eeb3fd1      0t0  UDP *:*
WiFiAgent  444 meysamfatheepanah    7u  IPv4 0x680181e2905ec219      0t0  UDP *:*
Telegram   584 meysamfatheepanah   23u  IPv4 0x680181e29016bba1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:49367->91.108.4.170:443 (ESTABLISHED)
idea      1236 meysamfatheepanah   21u  IPv4 0x680181e2944c39b1      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:51541 (LISTEN)
idea      1236 meysamfatheepanah   35u  IPv4 0x680181e29f19aba1      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:51541->127.0.0.1:51670 (ESTABLISHED)
idea      1236 meysamfatheepanah   95u  IPv4 0x680181e292c33ba1      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6942 (LISTEN)
idea      1236 meysamfatheepanah  164u  IPv4 0x680181e2905ec6e9      0t0  UDP 192.168.1.61:53244
idea      1236 meysamfatheepanah  165u  IPv4 0x680181e2905f0a49      0t0  UDP *:9876
idea      1236 meysamfatheepanah  624u  IPv4 0x680181e2939c30b9      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:63342 (LISTEN)
idea      1236 meysamfatheepanah  625u  IPv4 0x680181e2936275d1      0t0  TCP *:2864 (LISTEN)
idea      1236 meysamfatheepanah  626u  IPv4 0x680181e2905bb709      0t0  UDP *:2863
idea      1236 meysamfatheepanah  770u  IPv4 0x680181e29361b9b1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51539->208.68.163.218:5222 (ESTABLISHED)
java      1329 meysamfatheepanah  123u  IPv4 0x680181e293619ec9      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:51670->127.0.0.1:51541 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   37u  IPv4 0x680181e29325b7c1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51739->172.217.18.226:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   41u  IPv4 0x680181e2944862a9      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51692->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   42u  IPv4 0x680181e29325dba1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51736->74.125.206.94:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   43u  IPv4 0x680181e2929fc2a9      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51804->50.31.164.173:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   44u  IPv4 0x680181e2939c42a9      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51737->216.58.208.238:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   50u  IPv4 0x680181e29f06d9b1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51733->172.217.19.131:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   54u  IPv4 0x680181e2929f9ec9      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51682->216.58.208.238:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   59u  IPv4 0x680181e294498ba1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51738->216.58.208.238:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   61u  IPv4 0x680181e29362a2a9      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51686->216.58.211.100:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   71u  IPv4 0x680181e29448a9b1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51673->104.16.112.18:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   74u  IPv4 0x680181e29f0a75d1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51791->64.233.167.95:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   75u  IPv4 0x680181e2944d79b1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51753->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   79u  IPv4 0x680181e2929fb0b9      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51798->216.58.208.200:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   82u  IPv4 0x680181e2929fcba1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51799->23.235.43.175:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   87u  IPv4 0x680181e294482ba1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51800->50.31.164.172:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   88u  IPv4 0x680181e2932997c1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51774->216.58.208.227:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   92u  IPv4 0x680181e29f13c7c1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51767->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   93u  IPv4 0x680181e292c305d1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51802->23.51.123.27:80 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah   95u  IPv4 0x680181e2944c30b9      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51785->23.51.123.27:80 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox   1331 meysamfatheepanah  101u  IPv4 0x680181e296a4f7c1      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.61:51768->172.217.20.42:443 (ESTABLISHED)
```

and for this command i give this output

```
Meysams-MacBook-Pro:~ meysamfatheepanah$ sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
COMMAND  PID              USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
idea    1236 meysamfatheepanah   21u  IPv4 0x680181e2944c39b1      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:51541 (LISTEN)
idea    1236 meysamfatheepanah   95u  IPv4 0x680181e292c33ba1      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6942 (LISTEN)
idea    1236 meysamfatheepanah  624u  IPv4 0x680181e2939c30b9      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:63342 (LISTEN)
idea    1236 meysamfatheepanah  625u  IPv4 0x680181e2936275d1      0t0  TCP *:2864 (LISTEN)


Meysams-MacBook-Pro:~ meysamfatheepanah$ netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen"
tcp4       0      0  localhost.51541        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.astromed-main        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  localhost.63342        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  localhost.6942         *.*                    LISTEN
```

i think another process from osx or etc use from port 80 .
have any idea about it?

Comment: Did this error happen when you ran you project in first time?

Comment: yes i give this error when run the project first time , i must use this port 80 for many reason in my project.

Comment: This does not work on a Mac for the same reason it does not work on any other Unix based operating system. See [Why is sudo required to start up a webserver on a given ip:port?](http://superuser.com/questions/289833/why-is-sudo-required-to-start-up-a-webserver-on-a-given-ipport/289844#289844) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try `$ sudo lsof -Pn -i | grep ":80 (LISTEN)"`

I expect you'll get something like

```
httpd     6477            root    5u     IPv6 0x261be06accde8493        0t0                 TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd     6484            _www    5u     IPv6 0x261be06accde8493        0t0                 TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

which means: your mac web service is running.
If you're on Mountain Lion or newer, I also expect you had it once enabled in older OS versions via [sharing dialog](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/112). Unfortunatly [Apple removed this setting](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/) but didn't disabled the service ... that's how it looks to me. Perhaps it has been reset via timeMachine restore in background too

- temporary unload: `sudo apachectl stop`
- [permanent unload](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/setup-local-web-server-apache-php-osx-yosemite.html): `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`